# Iterate over Multidimensional Arry for specific values

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to iterate over my multidimensional array to get the index of the selected value for each nested array. For instance, when I run my loop, I am comparing $income to see if it is between the 'Ranges'of each array. When the 'Range' is found I want to take that range $x and use it to make caluclations based on the 'MinTax' and 'Rates' for each nested array. So far I am able to iterate over $TAX_RATES array but not sure how to store the index of each nested array. Not sure what to do up to this point. Here is the code.

```
<?php

$income = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'income'); 
define('TAX_RATES',
array(
 'Single' => array(
  'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
  'Ranges' =>array(0,9275,37650,91150,190150,413350,415050),
      'MinTax'=>array(0,927.50,5183.75,18558.75,46278.75,119934.75,120529.75),
  ),
  'Married_Jointly' =>array(
    'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
    'Ranges' =>array(0,18550,75300,151900,231450,413350,466950),
    'MinTax' =>array(0,1855.00,10367.50,29517.50,51791.50,111818.50,130578.50),
  ),
  'Married_Seperately' =>array(
    'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
    'Ranges' =>array(0,9275,37650,75950,115725,206675,233475),
    'MinTax'=>array(0,927.50,5183.75,14758.75,25895.75,5599.25,65289.25),
  ),
  'Head_Household' =>array(
    'Rates' => array(10,15,25,28,33,35,39.6),
    'Ranges' =>array(0,13250,50400,130150,210800,413350,441000),
    'MinTax' => array(0,1325.00,6897.50,26835.00,49417,116258.50,125936)
  )
 )
);

  function incomeTax($income){
    foreach(TAX_RATES as $lvl => $lvl_data){
        $x=0; 
        while ($x <=7){
          if($income>=TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges'][$x] 
          && $income<=TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges'][$x+1]){              
          return $income=TAX_RATES[$lvl]['MinTax'][$x]
                 +((TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Rates'][$x]*.01)
                 *($income-(TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges'][$x])));
            } 
        $x++; 
        }   
  }    
  };

$results = incomeTax($income);

?>
```

Comment: Im wondering if I should store the indexes in an array and return the array and use the array to make the caluculations on for each nested array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out thanks to this forum. https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/556d9d0ad3292f03fb000558. Here is my new code.

```
function incomeTax($income){
    foreach(TAX_RATES as $lvl => $lvl_data){         
        for($i=0; $i<count(TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges']); $i++){
          for($l=0; $l<count(TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges'][$i]); $l++){

          if($income>=TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges'][$i] 
          && $income<=TAX_RATES[$lvl]['Ranges'][$i+1])
            {
            echo $i; 
            }
          }
        }

   } 
};
```

Comment: This prints out the indexes from each array that fall within the conditions of my if statement.